# How can I move large binaries from main to a git submodule?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-submodules

I have a bunch of videos inside a directory named "videos". I committed that unfortunately large folder to git, causing git to become very slow for some activities such as cloning. So I did some research and discovered git submodules, but I don't seem to understand them very well.

Here's what I did:

1. I created a separate repository just for the videos at ssh://dev.example.org/var/git/project/microsite_videos and put the videos in there.
2. I deleted the videos from my main repo at ssh://dev.example.org/var/git/project/microsite and committed the delete. I realize this doesn't remove the videos from history, but I wanted to make sure I understood submodules before I change history.
3. I added the videos back as a submodule:

   ```
   git submodule add ssh://dev.example.org/var/git/project/microsite_videos videos
   ```
4. I committed these changes to master.

Here is my .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "videos"]
    path = videos
    url = ssh://dev.example.org/var/git/project/microsite_videos
```

At first it seemed to work OK, but I'm confused about some of its behavior. In particular, just now I merged master into a branch and the videos folder just disappeared. The .gitmodules file is still there, but any attempt to pull or update the videos folder just gives me a new prompt without appearing to do anything.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I improve the my understanding of submodules so I don't have to flounder every time I try to branch and merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that submodules are just a pointer to a specific commit of a specific repo.
See "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)".

Meaning that, after your merge, you still have your pointer (in .gitmodules and as a special entry in the tree), but you need a `git submodule update` in order to refresh the submodule content.
See "[Git submodule head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head)" if that update should fail.