# Git submodule: Reference is not a tree

Tags: git, git-submodules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git submodule head ‘reference is not a tree’ error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error)

This error with Git:

> fatal: reference is not a tree:
>   081fe062d788900919a64d2222891a7357aa1364

I know this error is suppose to be something like a commit that has not pushed up yet. But it can't be?!

I cloned Mapbox-ios-sdk from Github. Mapbox-ios-sdk has this FMDB module (yet another Git repo), which I sort of modified (I simply add a file with some C macro).

So this is what (I think) I did:

(1). github fork FMDB, cloned my fork, modified it, push it back to my fork.

(2). Clone mapbox-ios-sdk, switch branch to develop (cuz I need it). Remove original FMDB module, add my fork of FMDB module.

After that when I clone from my mapbox-ios-sdk fork, switch branch to develop, no problem what so ever.

But really I got this master project which uses mapbox-ios-sdk:

(3) Remove mapbox-ios-sdk submodule from my master project.  Add a new submodule which is my own fork of mapbox-ios-sdk. Push it back to my Bitbucket private project.

Things now puke when I `git clone --recursive` on my private project. It'll say reference is not a tree. But clearly it is, because I'm still able to clone from my mapbox-ios-sdk fork!

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
Well I fixed it by re-doing all the steps. I still do not understand why `git clone --recursive mapbox-ios-sdk` works but not `git clone --recursive master_project` which incorporate mapbox-ios-sdk