# git checkout throws fatal reference is not a tree

Tags: git, capistrano

I deployed code using capistrano into a remote machine, but I get the following error. How do i get rid of this issue.

```
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:mycompany/foo.git staging"
    command finished in 468ms
  * getting (via checkout) revision df3d0367fd021d83f881f5d7261dba3f891bca22 to /tmp/20130503165924
    executing locally: git clone -q --depth 1 git@github.com:mycompany/foo.git /tmp/20130503165924 && cd /tmp/20130503165924 && git checkout -q -b deploy df3d0367fd021d83f881f5d7261dba3f891bca22
fatal: reference is not a tree: df3d0367fd021d83f881f5d7261dba3f891bca22
```

Comment: Could you add some information about your repository setup, plus the command you ran to get this output?

Comment: Its a github repository and the git clone and the subsequent checkout is causing this issue.

Comment: Could you try taking Capistrano out of the equation and just run the commands yourself (one at a time)? Please edit your question and include the commands you enter + their output.

Comment: @MattKantor I did that earlier and execute each step separately and got the exact same error

Comment: I've added some more commands to the ticket.

Comment: Is it possible there were a recetn pull request? https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/617#issuecomment-6691627

Comment: I think your answer could be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error

Comment: See there is a short answer too `git submodule sync` `git submodule update`

Comment: Try `composer clear`: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6641#issuecomment-424635069

Answer (score 5):

I had to deal with a broken repository too. After commenting out Capistrano's shallow clone option (`:git_shallow_clone, 1` which yields `--depth 1`) deployment worked well.

See the accepted answer of this question for a detailed explanation on how to possibly fix it: [Git submodule head 'reference is not a tree' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error)

Answer (score 1):

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: bf52fb66f4b518bfa579f62db632699ddb127e7b
```

Usually, this error occurs because your local workspace is unaware that a hash exists in the remote. You can run `git fetch` and rerun the `checkout` command.

I got this error when I was trying to update my submodule to the latest commit hash in the workspace. git fetch in the submodule directory solved it.