# Git submodule update: reference is not a tree... but commit IS there

Tags: git, git-submodules

First of all: yes, I've checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error) inside out - but my situation is different.

We have three modules here:

- an application `A`
- its base library `B` (a submodule of `A`)
- a component `C` (a submodule of `B`)

When trying to do `git clone --recursive https://url_of_A/`, we get an error when git attempts to fetch `C`:

```
Cloning into 'path/of/C'...
[...]
Checking connectivity... done
fatal: reference is not a tree: 92405dd9027a2d55d9dd6f5b26494eee0009e297
Unable to checkout '92405dd9027a2d55d9dd6f5b26494eee0009e297' 
   in submodule path 'path/to/C'
```

But guess what, there's no error when we do `git clone --recursive https://url_of_B/` - even though **the revision to check out is clearly the same**:

```
Cloning into 'path/of/C'...
Checking connectivity... done
Submodule path 'path/to/C': checked out '92405dd9027a2d55d9dd6f5b26494eee0009e297'
```

... even though remote pathes to `C` are the same!

What's even more puzzling: this behavior is observed at Windows 7/8 machines only (so far, at least). Windows Vista/XP machines somehow do the deep cloning with the same repositories without any glitches - and I really wonder how's THAT can be platform-dependent.

---

That's for the case, now the questions: 1) is there anyone with the same problem, and 2) what could be the workarounds? Note that *all* the components (A, B, and C) are not under our control, so 'switch to git-tree' and stuff like that just won't work, unfortunately.

Comment: What version of git are you using on win7 and WinXp machines?

Comment: Would that issue persists with a msysgit 1.8.5.2?

Comment: No, it seems to be gone after the update. :) Still would be great to have a reason for this behaviour. My searches gave me [this issue](https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/99), but it's not particularly explanative...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first (incomplete) answer, a lot of submodule corrections went between git 1.8.4 and 1.8.5.2:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git>git log -Ssubmodule v1.8.4..v1.8.5.2
```

- [commit ac1fbbda201](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac1fbbda2013416b6c6a93d65c5dcf6662a60579): `submodule`: do not copy unknown update mode from `.gitmodules`
- [commit 746593bdcaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/746593bdcaf86827e016c97e091442d6a227de0f): `refs`: remove unused function `invalidate_ref_cache`
- [commit 04c1ee576ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04c1ee576accad4d0a04f168b86992aba0a6727d): `mv`: Fix spurious warning when moving a file in presence of submodules
- [commit 927b26f87a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/927b26f87a5654349b87d3217ed8e9360d9ff798): submodule: don't print status output with `ignore=all`
- [commit 4b054402833](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b05440283350ec3b01afabe847d9ce5cf4cbdb7): avoid segfault on submodule.*.path set to an empty "true"
- [commit 95c16418f03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c16418f0375e2fc325f32c3d7578fba9cfd7ef): `rm`: delete `.gitmodules` entry of submodules removed from the work tree
- [commit 0656781fadc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0656781fadca17cc51fb1c30f265c251ebe12819): `mv`: update the path entry in `.gitmodules` for moved submodules
- [commit 8745024422d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8745024422d4b38d8bf93d342b7b173f57cbceaa): `parse_pathspec`: support stripping/checking submodule paths

It is possible one of those patches enhances the robustness of the submodule feature.
For instance, the msysgit issue [you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484004/git-submodule-update-reference-is-not-a-tree-but-commit-is-there/21530437#comment32509392_21484004) ([issue 99](https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/99)) could be solved with [commit 4b054402833](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b05440283350ec3b01afabe847d9ce5cf4cbdb7).

Comment: Thank you, been trying to figure this out for hours.