# How to setup submodule so that git clone --recursive always takes master of submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-clone

I've reference this: [Git submodule head 'reference is not a tree' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error)

And this: [git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189575/git-submodule-tracking-latest/9189815#9189815)

Possibly my problem is slightly different. (I'm assuming its the same but not doing something right...)

I want my git setup such that if I run:

```
git clone -b master --recursive /path/to/main/repo.git
```

the **submodules** **should always** be cloned against "master"

Otherwise, in many cases the referenced commit doesn't exist (The branch of the submodule) or are "out of date" causing the clone to fail with error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree
```

I've tried to setup the main repository to take the submodule master:

```
git submodule add -b master /path/to/submodule.git
```

But when cloning the main repo:

```
git clone -b master --recursive /path/to/main/repo.git
```

The submodule commit referenced doesn't exist (not taking master as expected)

Answer (score 3):

As submodule is never checked out against a branch.
It is always checked out at the SHA1 recorded by the [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

What you can do is:

- making sure the submodule is set to follow the `master` branch
  See "[How to make an existing submodule track a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)"
- do a `git submodule update --remote --recursive` to make sure each submodule fetch and update themselves against their respective `master` branch.