# git submodule is not syncing

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote

I have a git submodule. On the server I have set it up, everything is working fine. On a different server, it's not finding the revision in the submodule it should go to. All changes have been pushed to the remote repository. I tracked the problem down to the remotes, that I might have screwed up while setting them up.

On the server where everything is working:

```
$ cat .gitmodules 
> [submodule "foo/submodule"]
>         path = foo/submodule
>         url = https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/goodremote/submodule.git
$ cd foo/submodule/
$ git remote -v
> origin  https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/goodremote/submodule.git (fetch)
> origin  https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/goodremote/submodule.git (push)
> upstream        https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/badremote/submodule.git (fetch)
> upstream        https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/badremote/submodule.git (push)
```

The commit that is checked out resides on the `origin` remote, so I believe the `.gitmodules` is correct.

But here's what happens on the server where it's not working:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
> [submodule "foo/submodule"]
>         path = foo/submodule
>         url = https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/goodremote/submodule.git
$ git submodule sync
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
> Initialized empty Git repository in foo/submodule/.git/
> remote: Counting objects: 13483, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3001/3001), done.
> remote: Total 13483 (delta 10625), reused 13236 (delta 10444)
> Receiving objects: 100% (13483/13483), 103.89 MiB | 24.57 MiB/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (10625/10625), done.
> fatal: reference is not a tree: 71a57a9551a3c10229b92d724716a0f897001dab
> Unable to checkout '71a57a9551a3c10229b92d724716a0f897001dab' in submodule path 'foo/submodule'
$ cd foo/submodule
$ git remote -v
> origin  https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/badremote/submodule.git (fetch)
> origin  https://:@gitlab.server.com:8443/badremote/submodule.git (push)
```

I understand the error message. The commit that is supposed to be checked out, is not to be found on that remote. However, I do not know how I can tell the submodule to use the right remote. Can I either define both remotes in the submodule or at least update the submodule to use the other remote? I believed this is what the `.gitmodules` is used for, but apparently it doesn't work.

Edit: I managed to fix this in an unsatisfactory way. I set up the repository including submodule on the new server until I hit the error outlined above. Then I go into the submodule, fix all the remotes and use `git submodule update`. While this is working, it is definitely not the way it is supposed to work. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Are you sure the commit you're trying to check out has been pushed to the location where you are trying to check them out? Sub-modules have to be pushed separately when changes are made locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodule head 'reference is not a tree' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error)

Comment: @Dekker Yes, I pushed inside out, first the submodule then the outer repository. But as can be read in the output, it's really looking for the commit on the wrong remote, that's all.

Comment: @1615903 This is not a duplicate. All the steps outlined in there, I've tried, as can be seen in my post.

Comment: Ah true - retracted my close vote.

Comment: Why the downvote?