# git: webrtc: "reference is not a tree" but i can see commit in UI

Tags: git, webrtc

I can see commit in UI, but I can't checkout it:

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2155887/4778809

Comment: Do you have the commit locally? What does `git log -1 9f7e2a9` print? If it does not exist yet, run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin <branch>` first.

Comment: you can see i called `git fetch`. also there is no such commit in my local git repo /tmp/webrtc2 asmirnov$git log -1 9f7e2a90da243288657e1802af85168e87daab01
fatal: bad object 9f7e2a90da243288657e1802af85168e87daab01

Comment: First of all, "commit id" is on your current branch.
If not, you cannot "git checkout commit_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$ gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags
```

Instead of just

```
$ gclient sync
```

Answer (score 4):

The web interface to the WebRTC repository will let you access commits that are not reachable from any branch.  Commit `9f7e2a90da243288657e1802af85168e87daab01` is one of these commits: it's not on any branch at all.

You can obtain it as a local branch named `pr/65` using:

```
git fetch origin +refs/branch-heads/65:refs/heads/pr/65
```

though how someone other than me would find this, I'm not sure. :-)

(This particular repository seems to be set up with some sort of bug management system that I am not familiar with.  There's a link from https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=8962 to the internal bug page that is in the log message for `9f7e2a90da243288657e1802af85168e87daab01`, but I'm not allowed access to the corresponding page.)

Comment: It's strange chromium uses it in release 65.0.3325.181 (https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/abb5172872b726072a64dfabaf45894c6ecf7369/DEPS#L568) and does not fail.

Comment: can you suggest how we can deal with this case while building Chromium (it uses `gclient sync`) without manual switching to local branches?

Comment: @4ntoine: I have no idea; I have never touched `gclient`, whatever that is.