# Why am I unable to checkout a commit in git

Tags: github, git-commit, git-rebase

I see error while trying to checkout a commit

```
git checkout 430f6c81c0a39b58b557b53e9569d9b786731d82
fatal: reference is not a tree: 430f6c81c0a39b58b557b53e9569d9b786731d82
```

Is there any work around for this
I am able to see the commit in UI
https://github.com/IBM/ibmcloud-volume-vpc/tree/430f6c81c0a39b58b557b53e9569d9b786731d82

Comment: Please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155887/git-submodule-head-reference-is-not-a-tree-error

Comment: I'm not seeing the commit on GitHub (there's a big fat warning: »This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.«). Do you have an up-to-date local clone of the repo (`git fetch --all`)? Also, from where did you get that commit hash; why do you want to check out this commit?

Comment: Voting to close since this question does not include nearly enough information to be answerable and no clarification was provided in over a month.